# Http send is not working with encoded url parameters

Tags: apex, callout, apexrest

I created one class to make http callout to ftp server.I am using Http mock for test class.Sometimes ftp folders are created with space and it is required to encode the file and folder name in ftp url.
1. In first screenshot, i m using http request without encode
2.In 2nd screenshot I have encoded file name and folder name

I ran same test class for both, in first scenario http send method is executed.In second scenario http send method is not executing.

Can someone provide correction and explanation for it ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Execution of `req.setEndpoint` in test-class throws some exception. That is why after that is goes to `catch` block and callout is not sending at all. Remove try-catch block and you will able to check thrown exception and will know exactly what is a problem.

In addition, I don't see what are you doing in `catch` block, but catching general `Exception` is  a bad practice. Catch exception only if you know what you have to do it with it.

Here is a nice [Pokemon Catch](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136920/pokemon-catch-generic-exception-handling-in-apex/136922#136922) sfdcfox's answer

Comment: Hi Oleksandr,
ts weird that its working in actual scenario (trying from UI). URL encode should not break the call.